# Connection Not Established with server sometimes while connecting through website

Tags: asp.net, mariadb, mariadb-10.5

I am fetching data from database (MariaDB) through website (Via Functions / Procedures) . But it sometimes fetch data from database for some requests but sometimes it throws error for same id like e.g  "connection attempt failed because the connected party not properly respond after a period of time. or established connection failed because connected host failed to respond."  I have also attached error files.
and sometimes it throws error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

The point is this when we are run website on localhost then it works properly but while host on our live server over internet then it throws error for sometimes.

in addition it also submitted that no. of users (approx. 600 persons) fetching data from that application but sometimes its throws error.

My question is this is it problem with our database server or our application .

we suspect that this problem with database server because it break the connection sometime then we refresh the connection then its gave data .

if is it then let me know what are setting we can do on database so that we resolve this problem.

[[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRW6U.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRpGz.jpg)

[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCd28.jpg)

What we can do to resolve this problem on database server or webserver .

version we are using mariadb is 10.5.19 and iis 10